# Subtract 7 days from today

Tags: sql, hive

I am new to hive and sql.

Is there any way to get the current date - 7 in Hive, i.e. the date 7 days ago. And date in my table is in the format `20150910`. (`yyyyMMdd`).

I tried below query, but it's not returning anything.

```
select *
from gmr.tedf_cs_mrch_tran
where cpd_dt = FROM_UNIXTIME(
                 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
                  DATE_SUB(
                    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd') , 7 ), 'yyyyMMdd'))
limit 10;
```

Kindly please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
select *
from table1
where dt >= date_sub(from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp()/(60*24*24))*60*24*24), 7) and
      dt < date_sub(from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp()/(60*24*24))*60*24*24)), 6);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick turn around. i shall try now and let u know .

Comment: Its throwing an error-'' invalid table alias or column reference 'current_date'.

Comment: Try the tried-and-true:  `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())` for the current date.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the Condition in where clause :

```
(((unix_timestamp(usage_dt,'yyyy-MM-dd')) >= (unix_timestamp(date_sub(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd') ,7),'yyyy-MM-dd'))) and ((unix_timestamp(usage_dt,'yyyy-MM-dd')) <= (unix_timestamp(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy-MM-dd'))))
```

Here usage_dt is you column name for date, and the DateFormat In Hive used as "yyyy-MM-dd" format so if you are havig any other format you can mention as here 
yyyyMMdd is the customr format of the sate.

`((unix_timestamp(usage_dt,'yyyy-MM-dd')) <= (unix_timestamp(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyyMMdd'))`

There is also alternate option to use DateDiff in where condition like

```
(datediff(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()), usage_dt) <= 7)
```

Hope thses will work for you

Comment: Hi debjit thanks for the quick turn around. my requirement got changed.Is there any way if we run a query today with count fields then it should fetch last 7 days data ( example- if i run a query with count fields on monday then I should get the total count from last week monday to sunday) And date in my table is in the format 20150910. (yyyyMMdd).

Comment: The Above exmaple, will do  check the calculation like it will take only last 7days Data, as we use datediss the value will be check curent_date and given date differecne , and if its less than equal to 7 it will take the same repected fileds only. for More Manupulation of Date You can check the [**URL**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) , also there was more example mention in Forum You will get it :)