# Return last week data in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I am new to hive and sql.

Is there any way if we run a query today with count fields then it should fetch last 7 days data ( example- if i run a query with count fields on monday then I should  get the total count from last week monday to sunday) And date in my table is in the format `20150910`. (`yyyyMMdd`).

Kindly please help me on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subtract 7 days from today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500380/subtract-7-days-from-today)

Comment: Use trunc and weekofyear functions

Comment: Thanks for the quick turn around....Can you kindly  give the full query with the function  as i am quiet new tohive and sql

Answer (score 7):

You can use date_sub() in this case. Something like this should work...

```
select * from table
where date_field >= date_sub(current_date, 7)
```

assuming that the current day's data is not loaded yet. If you want to exclude the current day's data too, you will have to include that too in the filter condition

```
 and date_field <= date_sub(current_date, 1)
```

current_date would work **if your hive version > 0.12**
else, you can explicitly pull the date from unix using `to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()))`

Comment: Hi Anil- I tried: select * from table1
 where cpd_dt >= date_sub(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())), 7) and
      cpd_dt <= date_sub(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())), 1);  but this returned no results. can u please elaborate how to give filter condition in the above queryas i dont have date loaded for today and yesterday.

Comment: I think the issue is because of the type mismatch. Try casting the date obtained from to_date to date data type do you have data for today?
If yes, have you tried checking
select * from table1 where cpd_dt = cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())) as date)
If this works, you should be able to use the query accordingly

Comment: Anil I gave a run for the above casting date  query .It says no operation results. I have data loaded untill 09/09.means i dont have todays and yesterday data loaded. my requirement is if i run my query with count fields on wednesday it should fetch 1 week data from last week monday to current week monday.

Comment: @Ramya Its funny that your requirements evolve new with time ;)
There are a couple of ways to get this done. one of them would be to define the week_start_date and week_end_date in the conf and then get the data.
The other method would be to generate the dates using shell commands. Both are doable.
but let me know if you are able to fetch data for any of the dates using the command. if yes, what command are you using?

Comment: @Anil..thanks  for taking your time  and responding to my requirements. Actually i am building a data set with 27 columns coming  from 7 tables. Most of the columns are count and with filter conditions. I am not sure how to accomplish this task with many expressions and join them.. Can you please let me know if u can help me out and  how to way to share my hive query which i worked on  till now.Does sharing in emails accepted here.